# how to use activityResultContract to get the result if user back from wifi setting kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, wifi, android-settings

how to use activityResultContract to get the result in boolean (true/false) if the user back from wifi setting in kotlin

if user is back from wifi setting, then just return true
if user is back from for example lock screen, then return false

i have use activity contract

```
class WifiSettingChangeContract : ActivityResultContract<Unit?, Boolean>() {

    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Unit?): Intent {
        return Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS)
    }

    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): Boolean {

        return resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK
    }
}
```

but it always return false

any help regarding this?

Comment: What kind of result are you after? What would true or false mean?

Comment: - true  ==  user is back from the wifi setting page, then i want to do something
- false == user is not returning from the wifi setting page

Comment: That is nonsense as when parseResult() triggers the user is back. Did you inspect that intent?

Comment: so, when i made activity result contract for this, just return true in the parseResult because it indicate the user back from wifi settings?

Comment: i inspect the intent, the intent return null

Comment: You are programming and testing your app. So when you come back from settings parseResult() is called? Then you know. for the rest i dont understand..